# Effectively indexing array column in Dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I can get what I need by using the code below but it's incredibly slow because of using collect and defining a new RDD at each step of the loop, which I know is terrible practice...

I need to apply a StringIndexer to each element of a Dataframe col (event_name) which looks like this :

```
+--------------------+-------+-------+---------+----------------+
|               email|country|manager|       bu|      event_name|
+--------------------+-------+-------+---------+----------------+
|xxxxxxxx@xxxxxxx....|     GB|   0   |Core - CS| [event1,event2]
|xxxxxxxx@xxxxxxx....|     GB|   0   |Core - CS| [event3] 
|xxxxxxxx@xxxxxxx....|     GB|   0   |Core - CS| [event1,event2]
|xxxxxxxx@xxxxxxx....|     CA|   0   |Core - CS| [event3,event4,event3]
|xxxxxxxx@xxxxxxx....|     US|   0   |Core - CS| [event1]         
+--------------------+-------+-------+---------+----------------+
```

I need this event_name col to be transformed and replaced or appended to this DF, something like:

```
+--------------------+-------+-------+---------+----------------+
|               email|country|manager|       bu|      event_name|
+--------------------+-------+-------+---------+----------------+
|xxxxxxxx@xxxxxxx....|     GB|   0   |Core - CS| [1,2]
|xxxxxxxx@xxxxxxx....|     GB|   0   |Core - CS| [3] 
|xxxxxxxx@xxxxxxx....|     GB|   0   |Core - CS| [1,2]
|xxxxxxxx@xxxxxxx....|     CA|   0   |Core - CS| [3,4,3]
|xxxxxxxx@xxxxxxx....|     US|   0   |Core - CS| [1]         
+--------------------+-------+-------+---------+----------------+
```

Any ideas how I can do this without the massive overheads below?

thanks

```
  val rddX = dfWithSchema.select("event_name").rdd.map(_.getString(0).split(",").map(_.trim replaceAll ("[\\[\\]\"]", "")).toList)
  //val oneRow = Converted(eventIndexer.transform(sqlContext.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq("CCB")).toDF("event_name")).select("eventIndex").first().getDouble(0))
  rddX.take(5).foreach(println)
  val severalRows = rddX.collect().map(row =>
    if (row.length == 1) {
      (eventIndexer.transform(sqlContext.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(row(0).toString)).toDF("event_name")).select("eventIndex").first().getDouble(0))
    } else {
      row.map(tool => {
        (eventIndexer.transform(sqlContext.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(tool.toString)).toDF("event_name")).select("eventIndex").first().getDouble(0))
      })
  })
```

Comment: I've also tried this:

`val toTransform = dfWithSchema_filt.select("event_name").flatMap(_.toString.split(",").map(_.trim replaceAll ("[\\[\\]\"]", "")))`

But I've no idea how to keep track of the original index for the entry when there are multiple events in the original entry

Comment: Don't use `collect`, take advantage of the distributed nature of Sparks computation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have an easy solution, which would be to explode the events, apply the indexer then aggregate them back:

// This should typically apply all the required transformation using org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

```
def string2list = (regexp_replace(_: Column, "[\\[\\]\"]", "")) andThen
(split(_:Column, ","))
```

// First explode your list of event (Here it returns a dataframe and not an rddX)

```
val dfX = dfWithSchema
.withColumn("rowID",monotonically_increasing_id())
.withColumn("exploded_events", explode(string2list($"event_name")))
```

Apply your stringIndexer like (https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/ml-features.html#stringindexer)

```
val indexer = new StringIndexer()
  .setInputCol("exploded_events")
  .setOutputCol("categoryEventName")

val indexedEvents = indexer.fit(dfX).transform(dfX)
indexedEvents.show()
```

// Then if you need to get the data back as a List

```
val aggregatedEvents = indexedEvents
.groupBy("rowID").agg(collect_list("categoryEventName"))
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed thanks. Unfortunately I can't upvote you cause of rep, sorry!

Comment: Happy to hear that I could help.
No worries, however as the asker you can still [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) the answer if you want.